# Converting Access Query to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

After yeas of lurking on stackoverflow, always finding my answer), I finally need to post my own question.

I new to MySQL and have been using access query designer to help me learn/convert my query to SQL.

This has work fine until I tried to convert a access query that uses another query (sub-query).

Here is the finished Access query that works:

```
SELECT all_assm_start_stop.*, employee.first_name
FROM all_assm_start_stop LEFT JOIN employee ON all_assm_start_stop.employee_id = employee.employee_id
```

*all_assm_start_stop* is based on this access query:

```
(SELECT assemblies.assemblies_id, assemblies.assembly_name, labor.start_time, labor.stop_time, labor.number_completed, labor.employee_id, assemblies.product_id
FROM labor RIGHT JOIN assemblies ON labor.assemblies_id = assemblies.assemblies_id
WHERE (((assemblies.product_id)=2)))
```

I've been researching most the day about MySQL sub-queries but can't figure out how to convert this.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Unexpected results?  The "finished Access query" above should work on MySQL.

Comment: There's nothing to 'convert'.

Comment: Is all_assm_start_stop  a view or a table?

Comment: @Strawberry Neither really, but MSAccess lets you use other queries you've saved in it as if they were tables/views. Since it does not support subqueries at all (at least when I was developing under it), this method was the only "in Access" solution for queries that needed them.

Comment: @Uueerdo I see - that makes more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone who has had to do this too many times, this is the most direct/literal conversion method I have found:

```
SELECT all_assm_start_stop.*, employee.first_name
FROM ([original query]) AS all_assm_start_stop 
LEFT JOIN employee ON all_assm_start_stop.employee_id = employee.employee_id
;
```

*(Note the `[original_query]` is where you would put the second one you supplied, I posted the answer in this way for brevity and clarity/generality.)*

Edit: If that query was used in a lot of other queries, you might want to consider making it a [VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! Very impressed with the quick response of this community!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.assemblies_id
     , a.assembly_name
     , l.start_time
     , l.stop_time
     , l.number_completed
     , l.employee_id
     , a.product_id
     , e.first_name
  FROM assemblies a
  LEFT
  JOIN labor l
    ON l.assemblies_id = a.assemblies_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN employee e 
    ON e.employee_id = a.employee_id
 WHERE a.product_id = 2
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a fan of `RIGHT JOIN` either. ;)